# Charset encoding difference between a pair of server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, character-encoding, apache2

i have a pair of servers.
A local server for development and a remote vps for deployment.

I'm copying the project from the local server to the remote and i have problem with the charset.
I have yet setupped the UTF-8 in the head of the HTML document. The text with this error is picked by a SQL Query. Where is the problem?

The first image is the local server without error

[image: This is the local server]

The second image is the remote server with encoding error

[image: This is the remote server]

Comment: Encoding is broken somewhere. In your app (check headers), in database (check database/tables/columns encoding). Check if everywhere is UTF8, we can't help you more from screenshots.

Comment: It seems likely your production MySQL server's default character sets are different from the local server's. Always set up utf-8 in your HTML page headers, so you don't have to guess  what your browsers are doing.  This may help you figure it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through